# Regex to match numbers, special chars, spaces and a specific whole word?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a Regex to match numbers, special chars, spaces and a specific whole word ("ICT").

Example for the string:

```
[Columbia (ICT-59)]
```

Currently I've this Regex to match the  numbers, special chars and spaces:

```
[\W\s\d]
```

And this one to for the word "ICT":

```
(ICT)
```

How can I match both of this in one Regular expression?

Comment: e.g. **[** Columbia **(ICT-59)]** (everything that's bold + spaces)

Comment: I want to use the regex to split a string and only return a list with the actual content

e.g. the String is: [Columbia (ICT-59)], [Arizona (ICT-60)]

The list elments should be "Columbia" and "Arizona", and therfore I want to put in put in a regex that would match numbers, special chars, spaces and the word "ICT". OFC I could just take the regex **[\W\s\d]** and filter the "ICT" out later, but I kinda would like to combine it in one Regex.

Comment: So why not match using `[\h\d\W]+|\bICT\b` and replace with just empty string?

Comment: @ anubhava: because I'm really horrible at regex. I was basicaly missing the inclusive OR.

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```
/(?<=\[)[a-zA-Z]+\s\(ICT-\d+\)(?=\])/g
```

or

```
/^\[[a-zA-Z]+\s\(ICT-\d+\)\]$/g
```

You can use `\w+` at the position of `[a-zA-Z]`, if you want to allow digits and special characters at the position of the Location.

demo:

https://regex101.com/r/ZS0jeO/1

https://regex101.com/r/hpQok3/1

Comment: Thank you, but that way it would also match "Columbia", my goal is to match everything _except_ for the actual content (e.g. Columbia, Arizona…)

Comment: if `[Columbia (ICT-59)]` is your input then what is your output?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the part the you want in a capture group right after the opening `[` and match the rest of the format.

```
\[([^()]+?)\s*\(ICT-\d+\)]
```

- `\[` Match `[`
- `([^()]+?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ chars other than `(` or `)`, as few as possible
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `\(ICT-\d+\)` Match `(ICT-` 1+ digits and `)`
- `]` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PEmJra/1)

Or matching just a single word using `\w+`

```
\[(\w+)\s*\(ICT-\d+\)]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f6de7X/1)